# Why, in a c# test class, is the Selenium Wait no longer timing out

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a small extension method to find an element using the WebDriverWait

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }

        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
```

It has worked reliably previously, but it is no longer working correctly. The problem is that the timeout is no longer being applied. It will keep looking indefinitely at least until the call to the web driver times out.
This is a C# test program, and the driver is the chrome driver. It is fairly typically called using find by XPath but We use other find types as well.
For example

```
var element = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//h1[@class='m-t30'][contains(.,'My Profile')]"), 15);
```

Any Idea why this is now failing>

Comment: When you debugged through, what was the value of `timeoutInSeconds`?

Comment: Did you set `implicitWait` somewhere in the code?

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that yesterday, I am not sure why it was done. WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300); Or why it is so long. We are still early in the process of figuring out how this works.

Comment: @mjwills The timeout is as expected, in the example above it is 15 seconds

Comment: @Fenio removing this did work, I am not sure why, If you have an explanation or link that explains it that would be great, but you should change your comment to an Answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Noel Added the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem you have is related to mixing `Explicit` and `Implicit` Wait.

Let me explain. 
`Implicit` wait causes Selenium's actions like `Click` or `SendKeys` to wait for a given amount of time. For example 300 seconds.

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }

        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
```

Given your code, the line

```
return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
```

causes the problem.

`wait.Until` runs first, and tries to invoke `findElement` method. Then `Implicit` wait comes in the way, and Selenium waits 300 seconds until `findElement` action is done. `Explicit` wait does not consider it as 300 seconds. Mixing both have UNPREDICTED OUTCOMES according to comments in Selenium library.

From my experience it looks like this pseudo-code:

```
for (int i = 500ms; i < timeoutInSeconds; i+=500ms) {
    Thread.Sleep(300*1000) //300 seconds
    Driver.FindElement();

}
```

That's how basically it's treated. Implicit wait causes Thread to stop, so the timer in Explicit Wait is ignored for given Thread.Sleep();

In your case, you used 15 seconds of `Explicit` wait and 300 seconds of `Implicit` wait.
Default pooling is every 500 miliseconds.

Basically, your wait would work during:
15 * 2 //how many times method `FindElement` is invoked
Multiply it by number of seconds in each Implicit Wait call from Find Element:
30 * 300 seconds. That gives 9000 which gives 150 MINUTES. It's over 2 hours.
That's why your code was stuck and Selenium timed out.

I hope I explained it correctly to you.